# How to get an element to scroll with the page... for only part of the page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

So I have been trying to get an element to scroll with the page, similar to `position: fixed;`. However unlike just fixed position I don't want it fixed to the page forever, once it reaches the bottom of its parent it stops there, even if the user continues scrolling down.

So far I have only looked for solutions to this problem in CSS as this is all I really know at this time. If there is a way please help with a good detailed explanation as to how and why it works.

Thanks for the help

Comment: You'll want to look into a js/jquery solution to do what you are after.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`position: sticky` does exactly what you want. But it is [not widely implemented](http://caniuse.com/#search=sticky) yet...

- Only safari has full support with the `-webkit` prefix.
- Chrome supports it on `<th>`, but not on `<thead>` or `<tr>` elements.
- Firefox doesn't support table elements at all.
- No support on IE or current Edge, but supposed to be supported in Edge 16

Here's how it would work:

**Note:** you must specify one of `top|left|right|bottom` (can be `0`), otherwise it is interpreted as `position: relative`.

```
thead { 
  position: sticky; /* -webkit-sticky for Safari */
  top: 10px;
  background: white; 
}
```

[JSFiddle example with a table header that works on Chrome and Safari](https://jsfiddle.net/vyt0gf25/2/)

There are polyfills too, the most current I know of if [Stickyfill](https://github.com/wilddeer/stickyfill). Unfortunately it doesn't work on Firefox tables either…